# OCaml does not like when the return type of the function. This function along with all of my functions that have operations are giving me errors?

Tags: ocaml

This function is supposed to tell the difference of each element of two list recursively. But when I run it, ocaml does not like the types and the concatenation.

```
let rec diffImRow image1Row image2Row =
    if List.length image1Row = 0
    then []
    else ((List.hd image2Row) - (List.hd image1Row)) :: diffImRow (List.hd image1Row), (List.hd image2Row)
;;
```

Comment: I think this is just a typo, you wrote `List.hd` instead of `List.tl` on the right side of `::` and put a `,`.

Comment: `List.length` is O(n), you should use pattern matching `match lst with | [] -> ... | x::xs -> ...` to decompose a list. This also binds the head and tail of a list to `x` and `xs` respectively.

Comment: You should also do this pattern matching on both imageXRow values. You can combine the pattern matching like, `match image1Row,image2Row with | [],[] -> ... | x::xs, y::ys -> ... , et cetera`. This will ensure you've taken care of all the exceptional cases in the code. For example, what if image2Row is [] in the above function (you call `hd` on it twice)?

Comment: ... this is why `List.hd` and `List.tl` are considered a 'code smell' in OCaml; you should be pattern matching to allow yourself and the compiler the chance to think about all the cases the code can take.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with this piece of the code: `diffImRow (List.hd image1Row), (List.hd image2Row)` Firstly, you are sending the head of each list on the right side of the :: operator. You want to recurse with the tail of each list on the right side.  In addition, you have a comma between the arguments. The code works as follows:

```
let rec diffImRow image1Row image2Row =
  if List.length image1Row = 0
  then []
  else ((List.hd image2Row) - (List.hd image1Row)) :: diffImRow (List.tl image1Row) (List.tl image2Row)
```